# Creating a String Array using for loop returning null array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am attempting to create a hashkey maker that breaks down a word, and compares its letters to an array with a letter of the alphabet in each index. When they are equal, It takes the position of that alphabet letter and plugs it into another array with a 0 in front if its in the first 9 cells. I keep getting a null array. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Also i apologize if its ugly, only a few months into programming, but i will take any other formatting suggestions that a professor likes to see.

My first attempt:`

```
public String key(String word){
    final char[] alphArray="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    String Key; String Value;
    int alphLength=alphArray.length;
    String wordNoSpace=word.replaceAll("\\s","");
    char[] wordArray= wordNoSpace.toCharArray();
    int wordLength=wordArray.length;
    String[] keyArray = null;               
    String tmp; String formattedTmp;               
         for (int i=0; i > wordLength; i++)
          {
            for(int j=0; j >alphLength; j++)
            {
             if (wordArray[i]== alphArray[j])
             {
              tmp=Integer.toString(j);
              formattedTmp=String.format("%02d",tmp);
              keyArray[i]=formattedTmp;
             }             
            }
          }
        Key=Arrays.toString(keyArray);
        return Key;
        }
}
```

Again, any help is appreciated greatly!

Edit: taking someones suggestion, my expected input/output would be'
Input: apple
output: 0116162518

currently im getting: [null, null, null, null]

Edit 2: removed my second attempt, since the first is the one i spent the most time on

Comment: Given a string "foo bar baz" what output would you expect ?

Comment: You should provide an example of what you expect as input and what you expect as output. Beside, instead of splitting by "", directly use charAt() and loop over the String' char. Also, define a "null" array ?

Comment: Which attempt are you asking about?  Please remove one of these, as it adds unnecessary confusion to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: @TheophileDano Sorry if i'm confused with the question, but wouldn't the output be foo bar baz?

Comment: @NoDataFound I made the edits to my post. I will try your suggestion. I appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't looked at *all* your code, but here are two obvious bugs:

```
for (int i=0; i > wordLength; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j > alphLength; j++)
```

unless `wordLength` and `alphLength` are negative numbers, these loops will never iterate, because the condition will be always `false`.

Try changing `>` to `<`:

```
for (int i=0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < alphLength; j++)
```

You would have discovered this very quickly yourself had you used a debugger. I recommend you learn how to use a debugger asap.

Comment: This is embarrassing, you were absolutely correct and its working. I'm a total coding noob, about 6 months in, and i'm using Netbeans. I thought it had a debugger but it did not alert me to anything, am i wrong in my assumption?

Comment: A debugger has nothing to warn you about for this kind of mistakes. Maybe if there were unsigned integer types in Java the static anylizer would warn you

Comment: @TheophileDano debugger never "warn" you about anything. A debugger would show you that the loops weren't being iterated, and *that* would immediately make you investigate why, you would then examine the length variables and evaluate the condition expressions, and voila - you would find out very quickly what your mistake was.

Comment: @Bohemian I didn't say that debuggers would warn you though